# Getting all properties of an Ember Data model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm looking to figure out how I can get all the properties of an Ember Data model. Even just by their keys. Several of the properties are `computed.or` or computed properties generally.

`modelName.eachAttribute()` and `Object.keys(modelName.toJSON())` get me close, but do not include computed properties.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @jacefarm - thanks, but per my comment above, `.toJSON()` does not include computed properties; the other solutions listed suffer this problem as well.